# AngularJS and generated elements

Tags: angularjs

We have some third party javascript components that are generating some html elements. I'd like to couple it with AngularJS.

I've tried this code

```
<div ng-controller="ExpensesCtrl">
    <form id="expensesform">
        <input type="text" ng-model="expense.name" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="expense.amount" />
    </form>
    <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>expense | json
</div>
```

---

```
function ExpensesCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.expense = {};
    $scope.add = function () {
        $("#expensesform").append("<input type='text' ng-model='expense.age' />");
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tChNh/

but it doesn't work like excepted.

Is there any chance to get this working ?

Comment: First off, your jsfiddle is giving errors. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/wXZL7
second, what are you trying to do?  In angular, you generally don't want to be manipulating the DOM inside your controller, but want to create a directive to do that.

Comment: Hi Andy. As I said we are using javascripts components for generating our forms. The add method is just simulating this behavior. The point is that dynamicly generated elemnts do not play well with anglurjs. I was just wondering if is there any chance to get it working in my scenario.

Comment: So for this particular scenario, you'd want to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wXZL7/1/.  Inject the $compile service.  Could you give an example of a real use case?  It's hard to know how to handle it

Comment: Well, this is what I was looking for. Thank you. Make it an answer an I will accept it.

Comment: But this is the absolute wrong way to do it with Angular.  You want to create a directive... I will put it up anyway I guess..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the wrong way to do it, but for this particular scenario you'd want to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wXZL7/1. Inject the $compile service.

Again, this isn't the right way to do it with Angular.  Angular's thing is 'You don't have to mess with the DOM in your controller, let the HTML and directives do that'.

You want to create a directive to wrap whatever is generating your elements and let that do it.  Read the directives guide for examples: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: I see, I should wrap the js component calls into an angular directive, right ?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The angular way, to have your model perfectly synced, and to dynamically add or remove input types would be with http://jsfiddle.net/3BVMm/1/

you should provide the plugin we are talking about here, maybe angular blows this plugin away with just a few codes...

Comment: The Fiddle didn't work for me due to a few different things. I made an update, in case it helps anyone: http://jsfiddle.net/J8qvP/

Answer (score 0):

I have found this answer: [Compiling dynamic HTML strings from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database)

Maybe it helps others. It describes how to use the `$compile` service to get Angular to know about the knew Code.