# How to get Angular to work for dynamically added object

Tags: angularjs

I have two files as described below. I am defining the controller in file_1.php

In file_2.php, I am 'require'ing the file_1.php, and then moving the ul into the div that is described in file_1.php

What I want to be able to do is - get the functions within the controller to work for the ul which was dynamically added. My guess is that, when the page was loaded, the ul block is seen as being outside the controller and so it doesn't work. On searching, I was able to see a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857110/angularjs-and-generated-elements) that involved $compile, but that works for ng-model, and not for repeat or {{}} either. I am new to Angular and would appreciate any help.

**file_1.php**

```
<?php
   <div id="box_1" ng-controller="MyCtrl"></div>
?>
```

**file_2.php**

```
<?php
   require 'file_1.php';
?>

<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in items">item.text</li>
</ul>

{{items}}

<script>
   function MyCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.items = [{text: "Item 1", text: "Item 2"}];
   }

   $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#box_1').append($('ul'));
   })
</script>
```

**Some information that I found:**
In the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) here, under section "Reasons behind the compile/link separation", they have explained why compiling is different for ng-repeat. Could anyone explain what it means exactly and/or the way to go about it? I tried compile - anything that is not in an ng-repeat works, but anything inside ng-repeat doesn't.

Comment: I think You should use directive to do this kinda thing. Actually, could you explain what exactly do you want to do here ? I meant why do you want to do this ?

Comment: I have some content that is generated via php, and some content that is static html. The php is reused in more than one html file. So the controller is there.

Comment: Did you look into [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude) to include ul inside #box_1 ?

Comment: I cannot use ng-include inside #box_1 because I am loading #box_1 inside file_2 and not the other way around

Answer (score 0):

Are you wedded to this file structure for some reason? What you're trying to do goes against the grain of angular and will thus be a pain. Angular is supposed to free you from the pain of DOM manipulation with jQuery.

It seems like using `$compile` should work, though. Can you show us what you're trying to do with it?

Why is it that you can't do something like this?

```
<div id="box_1" ng-init="items = [{text: "Item 1", text: "Item 2"}]">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.text}}</li>
    </ul>

    {{items}}
</div>
```

(The syntax might be a bit off on `ng-init`.)

Comment: shouldnt that be `{{ item.text }}` ?

Comment: The reason I am doing it this way is because I am reusing file_1.php in multiple files using 'require', like in file_2, for example. The content of file_1 is generated via php, but is common across files. So, I cannot initialise anything in file_1 which might be used in file_2 but not in file_3. Yes, I realised that Angular is not to be used in combination with DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to manipulate the DOM in a controller. Aside of that, doesn't *$scope.$apply()* help?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#box_1').append($('ul'));
      $scope.$apply();
})
```