# Is it possible to use JQuery includes with Angular Includes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am working on an application that utilizes both Jquery and AngularJS includes, however Angular does not seem to execute after Jquery has included a file that has AngularJS markup. Jquery is including the "top_nav.html" template and inside this template there lives a angluar ng-include calling cart.html". I need to figure out how to get the angular code to execute after being included by jQuery.

```
<div id="topNav"></div>

<script> 
  //outside the document ready statment
  $('#topNav').load('includes/top_nav.html'); 
<script>
```

top_nav.html:

```
<div>
 ... 
  <div ng-controller="shoppingCart"
   class="shopping-cart"ng-include="'includes/cart.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind an AngularJS controller to dynamically added HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20651578/how-to-bind-an-angularjs-controller-to-dynamically-added-html)

Answer (score 1):

The jquery load does an ajax request. When the ajax is resolved, the angular have already been bootstrapped (assuming you use `ng-app` directive), so the html chunk that have been dynamically loaded was not bootstrapped by angular.

So, I guess that on the [callback of the jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load#callback-function), you need to [manually bootstrap angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap) passing `<div id="topNav"></div>` as the context. Something like this:

```
var topNav = $( "#topNav" );
topNav.load( "includes/top_nav.html", function() {
  angular.bootstrap(topNav.find("> div")[0], ['topNavAngularModule']);
});
```

<sup>Note: I'm not sure, sorry, I haven't tested it, but I think it might only work if `#topNav` is located *outside* `ng-app`.</sup>

Comment: Try this: `angular.bootstrap(topNav.find("> div")[0], ['topNavAngularModule']);`, but I think it might only work if jquery is loading html outside `ng-app`. If that doesn't work, try the [possible duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20651578/1064325) provided by Professor Allman.

Comment: Got this to work by removing ng-app from the website to prevent auto loading. Thanks!

Comment: @CodedContainer Awesome! Just an observation: now, angular will only bootstrap the page _after_ the jquery loads the `top_nav.html`, decreasing loading performance a little bit. I hope it won't be an issue to your case.

Comment: Awesome, I was running into a problem were it was not loading the rest of my Angular app, but then I just added another ng-app where needed and the rest of the page works. Thanks for your help!