# ng-click not working after compile ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive

```
app.directive("dir", function($compile, $sce){
      return{
        restrict: "E",
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
          scope.$watch('content',function(){
            var html = $sce.trustAsHtml(attr.content);
            scope.alabala = $compile(html)(scope);
          },true);
        },
        template: "<div ng-bind-html='alabala'></div>",
      }
    });
```

a controller:

```
function MainController($scope, $http, customService, $location, $sce, $compile){
    $scope.init = function(){
        customService.get().success(function(data) {
                 var html = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
                $("#dir").attr("content", data);

            });
    };
}
```

and on my index page I have:

```
<div id="div" ng-controller="MainController" class="pull-right span3" ng-init="init()">
      <dir id="dir" ></dir>
</div>
```

my custom service returns every time a different html containing for example

```
<button ng-click='click()'>Click me</button>
```

What I am trying to do is every time when I push a different value in the content of my directive to compile it and put it in my html and handle the click function from my controller. Because I'm new to AngularJS I have been struggling with this problem for sometime. Please help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You don't need to deal with [$sce](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce) to meet your purpose.

You can pass your `HTML` as string to the directive. After compilation in the directive it'll work.

In `HTML` where you need the `directive`

```
<dir id="dir" content="myVal"></dir>
```

Set different value in `myVal` your controller

```
$scope.myVal = '<button ng-click=\'buttonClick()\'>I\'m button</button>'; // HTML as string
```

The `directive`

```
myApp.directive('dir', function($compile, $parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        scope.$watch(attr.content, function() {
          element.html($parse(attr.content)(scope));
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }, true);
      }
    }
  })
```

Check the <kbd>[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/v02xk1o3ORKaptzo40pj?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Works perfect! In the way I wrote it is the $sce the problem or Im not passing it the right way to the directive?

Comment: @Reza - Could you please explain what $watch and $compile doing here. Would be happy if you could explain your code.

Comment: Here `$watch` used for automatic rendering, it listening directive's `content` value if content changed then it works. If you think your directive works only single time then you don't need `$watch`. Here `$parse` used for parsing the string content and `$compile` will link newly generated `HTML` with `scope`.

Comment: @Reza Can you please tell me how to pass a templateUrl into $scope.myVal? Thanks!

Comment: @mila Here `$scope.myVal` is used to pass `HTML Content` as string NOT `url`. If you need to load a `template` then use directive's `templateUrl` like https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#template-expanding-directive

Comment: Thank you @Reza but I'm not sure templateUrl is my way to go since I need to load the template dynamically.

Comment: Then you can use `templateUrl` as `function` like 
`function(elem, attr){
      return 'customer-'+attr.type+'.html';
    }`. 
In your directive add a `type` attribute which indicate your template type and inside of function you can create your `dynamic template url`.