# AngularJS : How to bind an event to a dynamically generated html with ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a custom AngularJS directive. How to bind an event to the dynamically generated html which is generated by the directive itself. Upon research I found that we need to use **$watch** and **$compile**, but I couldn't get it working. I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370080/ng-click-not-working-after-compile-ng-bind-html) relevant to my question. What is the alternative for jQuery **ON** in AngularJS

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please check this out in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D5ll1mjzPVqbHHg2Tqb5)

```
app.directive( 'btn', [ '$sce', function( $sce ){ 
return { 
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div ng-bind-html="buttonHtml"></div>',
    link : function ($scope, element, attrs) {
    $scope.buttonHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('<button ng-click="showMessage()">Click Me</button>');
    $scope.showMessage = function () {
        alert("You clicked Me");
  }
} }; }]);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the code you tried already using $watch and $compile, which you couldn't get to work?

Comment: Could you show what you've got so far, it'd be easier to help you.

Comment: isn't jqlite is doing that for you?

Comment: @MichaelBromley Please wait. I will edit my question my question with code samples

Comment: @Jai - I don't know how to do it. Can we achieve this with jqlite?

Comment: @vishnu if you are able to post your code in http://plnkr.co/ that would be useful.

Comment: @Jai - I have edited my question. Please check it in plunker

Comment: `element.bind('click')` should work here, even with jqLite.

Comment: @ivarni - Please check this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/1IC3SzOkEuArq3vrDeEs?p=preview you will understand what I need.

Comment: the problem you are addressing is already mentioned
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370080/ng-click-not-working-after-compile-ng-bind-html/21374642)
...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this would do like this way:

```
app.directive('yourcustomdirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict : "E", //<---E is directive like <customdirective></customdirective>
    replace : true,
    template:"<button>Click me.</button>", // <---dynamically generated button
    link:function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.on('click', function(){ // <-----click event bound 
        alert(scope.greet); // <----alerts the greet in the scope
      });
    }
  };
});
```

### [Demo Plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/sAmljPAdUqa9UVrDxAxx?p=preview)

### [Demo Plunkr with ng-click.](http://plnkr.co/edit/sAmljPAdUqa9UVrDxAxx?p=preview)

Comment: I have an ng-click associated with this button. How to make that ng-click work.

Comment: @vishnu do make a function in the scope of controller and access that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I need that doGreet() function also inside the directive not in the controller.

Comment: The problem is while using ng-bind-html. The event is not getting triggered for the dynamic content. Please check this out in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/D5ll1mjzPVqbHHg2Tqb5

Comment: Consider if the variable 'element' here contains a markup like '<div><button id="btn1"></button></div>' how to bind the event only to the button.

Comment: @vishnu you have jqlite available in angularjs you can use this `element.find('button').on('click', callback);`. [Read about jQlite here...!](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please check this plunker link http://plnkr.co/edit/D5ll1mjzPVqbHHg2Tqb5?p=preview. How to use ng-bind-html and bind an event to its contents.

Comment: I want to do something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/1IC3SzOkEuArq3vrDeEs?p=preview

Comment: It is not working. This is exactly what I want to do. Please check now http://plnkr.co/edit/1IC3SzOkEuArq3vrDeEs?p=preview

Comment: what to check? it is alerting properly, elaborate your issue.

Comment: You can check the script.js file in plunker. It is not alerting. http://plnkr.co/edit/1IC3SzOkEuArq3vrDeEs?p=preview
I want to use ng-bind-html that binds a button to the div. Button has an onclick event that invokes MyClick() function. But the click event is not triggered because it is dyanamically generated. I think we need to use $watch and $compile, but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: Ohh! i see....update this plunkr with use of ng-bind-html and provide that to me then only i hope i could understand the issue better.

Comment: It is updated with ng-bind-html. Please check http://plnkr.co/edit/1IC3SzOkEuArq3vrDeEs?p=preview