# Is there a way to load data into script

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So in Angular i'm trying to do

```
$scope.data = "<script> alert('hi'); </script>";
```

But unfortunately that doesn't work. I also tried to add **ng-bind-html** but without any results.

```
{{data}}
```

also I tried to load data in a script tag but that also seems not to work. Is there a way to avoid this all? For example

```
$scope.data = "bob";
```

-

```
 <script>
    var name = {{data}};
    </script>
```

Comment: Your quote around "hi" is going to break that line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19846600/2025923

Comment: I could be wrong, but my understanding is that loading <script> tags into an HTML page after page load is really bad practice. You can't reliably count on your script being executed by the browser.

Comment: You should not be using Angular to load additional script tags. Why not just place the code into a file and load it?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a directive that will load the script into DOM dynamically.

**Markup**

```
<load-script ng-if="data" data="data"></load-script>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('loadScript', function($compile){

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      'data': '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.append($compile(scope.data)(scope))
    }
  }
})
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/J5CiD3k95PPMLtHuzfMr?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Your `$scope` will be already either within a `<script>` block or in a Javascript file.

Now, when/how do you want the `alert` to be called? If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, here's how to do it:

```
<div ng-click="doAlert()">
  Click here to see an alert
</div>
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.doAlert = function() {
   alert('hi);
};
```