# Getting Angular scope method for dynamically loaded element

Tags: jquery, angularjs

```
<div id="Some-div" data-ng-controller="SomeController">
</div>

angularModule.controller("SomeController", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.someFunction = function myfunction() {

    }    
}]);
```

When we use`getAngularControllerScope($('#Some-div'));` to get the scope the method `someFunction()` is accessible and can be called like this `getAngularControllerScope($('#Some-div')).someFunction()`

### But when the same div is loaded through an ajax call

`getAngularControllerScope($('#Some-div'));` has no methods available.
Please help.

#### Loading of the html

```
$http.post('/SomeController/MyPartialAction', { data: "value" }).success(function (response) {
//load the partial view HTML in the div
$("#MyDiv").html(response);        
});
```

Comment: how you  load it using ajax? get the html as string and put it in the html?

Comment: @K.Toress yes the div is in a partial view loaded with an ajax call

Comment: can u please show the way you attach html content?

Comment: @k.toress I am doing this in an mvc project. And the partial view content is loaded though ajax in a div.

Comment: please add the code for ajax and append the content to html?

Answer (score 1):

Angular won't compile html content that you put directly into the DOM. In order to get it to process directives, such as `ng-controller`, you need to compile it explicitly. Something like this should work:

```
newScope = $scope.$new();     // for a new child scope
newScope = $scope.$new(true); // for a new isolate scope
newScope = $scope;            // for an existing scope

$compile(insertedDomElement)(newScope);
```

Or you could use `ng-include`:

```
$scope.template = '<div id="Some-div" data-ng-controller="SomeController</div>';

<html><body>
  <ng-include src="template"></ng-include>
</body></html>
```

Cf.
[AngularJS How to dynamically add HTML and bind to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845950/angularjs-how-to-dynamically-add-html-and-bind-to-controller)

Comment: i used this compile, but when using compile any controller is defined into the HTML getting complied, need to be defined first

Answer (score 1):

you need to compile the element in order to attach it in to the current scope,

to do that, inject the [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service in to the controller,

> Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template function, which can then be used to link scope and the template together

```
angularModule.controller("SomeController", ["$scope", "$http", "$compile", function  ($scope, $http, $compile) {
    $scope.someFunction = function myfunction() {

    }    
}]);
```

compile and attach the html after the ajax, like,

```
$http.post('/SomeController/MyPartialAction', {data:"value"}).success(function(response) {
    //compile against the $scope here,
    var compiledElm = $compile(response)($scope);
    $("#MyDiv").html(compiledElm);        
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you really cant use the `$routes` to achieve this, then you can do like this, but the best possible way is using `$routes`.

wrap the `#MyDiv` with in a div and assign a `controller` to that div like, i have put `ParentCtrl`

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <button ng-click="getHtml()">attach html</button>
    <div id="MyDiv"></div>
</div>
```

and in `ParentCtrl` do the html content attachment. as below

```
app.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $compile) {
    $scope.getHtml = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            var html = '<div id="Some-div" data-ng-controller="SomeController">{{ name }}</div>';
            var compiled = $compile(html)($scope);
            $("#MyDiv").html(compiled);
        }, 1000);
     };
}
```

here is a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/DIR2HVEeDNSXp9tHlMNQ?p=preview)

Comment: i used this compile, but when using compile any controller is defined into the HTML getting complied, need to be defined first.

Comment: `<div id="Some-div" data-ng-controller="SomeController">
</div>` is this the content you load using `ajax`?

Comment: yes the loaded content is having a controller defined

Comment: ooh i think its better to use `$routes` then