# injecting html content in empty template

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I retrieve the code of an HTML page from a server thanks to a rest service and I want integrate the html code into an empty template

```
 .controller('TestController', ['$scope'  ,'$rootScope' , '$sce'  , function ($scope ,$rootScope,$sce) {
        var restHtml =$rootScope.test; //contains <div>Test</div>
        $scope.showHtml= $sce.trustAsHtml(restHtml );
    }]);
```

The template

```
<div ng-bind-html="showHtml"></div> <!-- didn't work and i want a solution without integrate my html code into a existing div -->
```

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS How to dynamically add HTML and bind to controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845950/angularjs-how-to-dynamically-add-html-and-bind-to-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally DOM manipulations should not happen in the controller, directives should be used for them.

To answer your question, you could [compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) the html into your tag. Get the html, find the element you want to insert the html in and use compile to do it. A good example of [compile](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/07/using-compile-in-angular.aspx).