# How do I insert Html code from server into Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The server return code html and i would insert this code in page. But if I insert with jquery , angular directive not function.
My code into controller:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'find.php',
                data:{url:$scope.url}
                  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    $("#center").remove(); 
                    var data=response.data;
                    $("#result").html(data);

                   }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    $("#center").remove();          
                    $("#result").html("ERRORE");
                  });

            }
```

This example is in Jquery. How in Angular?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845950/angularjs-how-to-dynamically-add-html-and-bind-to-controller

Answer (score 0):

In your success handler, You can store the response data into `$scope` variable, Like `$scope.data=response.data;`. Then you can use `ng-bind="data"` in your html.

`ng-bind` will render the html stored inside `$scope.data` on the view.

**[Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)**