# How to bind controllers to generated HTML pages dynamically in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

So far I have the ability to generate new HTML pages with PHP code. I already have some pages, but I can generate new with a click of a button. It sets it up in such a way that it stores all of its information in JSON file with: name of the file, "when" component for angular route provider, the templateUrl, and a controller name.

Here is an example of JSON file:

```
{
  "pages": [
    {
    "name": "index",
    "when": "/",
    "controller": "indexController",
    "template": "views/index.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need somehow to bind the controllers to these generated pages, so that they will point to my HTML code with **ng-view**.

My **HTML** code has this:

```
  <div ng-view class="{{pageClass}}"></div>
```

My **static Angular** code had this (written manually, not generated dynamically):

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.
when('/', {
  templateUrl: '/views/index.html',
  controller: 'indexController'
});
app.controller('indexController', function($scope) {
  $scope.pageClass = 'index';
});
```

The controller allowed me to insert index.html template onto the ng-view section with class="{{pageClass}}". (I also could have used ng-class="{pageClass}")

Now, however, I generate the pages **dynamically**, which doesn't register controllers and binds the templates to the pageClass:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

var $routeProviderReference;
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProviderReference = $routeProvider;
}]);

app.run(['$route','$http','$rootScope',function($route, $http, $rootScope){
  $http.get('temp.json') // load data 
  .then(function(data){
    var result = data.data.pages; // data from JSON file
    var i;
    var currentRoute;
    for (i = 0; i< result.length; i++){ // for every existing HTML page
      currentRoute = result[i];
      var routeName = currentRoute.when;
      $routeProviderReference.when(routeName, { // assign template and controller
        templateUrl: currentRoute.template,
        controller: currentRoute.controller
      });
    }
    $route.reload();
  });
}]);
```

I get an error with this method, even though is partially works: **Error: [$controller:ctrlreg]**

**How do I bind my controllers** in this case? It should look like this:

```
app.controller(currentRoute.controller, function($scope) {
  $scope.pageClass = currentRoute.name;
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS How to dynamically add HTML and bind to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845950/angularjs-how-to-dynamically-add-html-and-bind-to-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I had to modify the controller and turn it into a function:

```
templateUrl: currentRoute.template,
controller: function($scope) {
  $scope.pageClass = currentRoute.name;
}
```

This will paste a selected page into ng-view inside of **pageClass**