# Decorate HTML elements with directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm calling a API that returns HTML, containing some `code` tags.

I'm looking forward to decorate that element with a directive, but as the HTML is coming from the API, I unable to add an directive attribute.

Angular decorates elements such as `form` with directives so I though about doing something like that:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('code', function($log) {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $log.info('Code Directive');
    }
  };

});
```

Although the console log did not print. Am I missing something?

**EDIT:** I notice that the log works with `code` elements that are created before the API call. However when the API injects the code into the html, the directive doesn't run. Is there a way to manually make it run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile your html with [`$compile` service](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/docs/api/ng.%24compile):

```
$http.get('path/to/template')
  .then(function(response){
    $scope.html = $compile(response.data)($scope);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is coming from an API, it's probably being added to your page after Angular has compiled it -- meaning that the directive isn't wired into the page.

In order to make it work, you should $compile your new html after inserting it. See: [Compiling dynamic HTML strings from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database), and in particular the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18157958/149060

Which has:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
        ele.html(html);
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});

function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.click = function(arg) {
    alert('Clicked ' + arg);
  }
  $scope.html = '<a ng-click="click(1)" href="#">Click me</a>';
}
```