# Writing out supplied HTML and then changing it in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my angular app, I get handed a bunch of HTML from a backend API. That HTML contains things like this: `<p><img data-is-gallery="true" id="img0001" src=""></p>`

Elsewhere in the API response I have a list of image URLs by ID. I currently write the HTML into the page by setting `$scope.data` to the API response in my controller, and then

```
<div ng-repeat="block in data.htmlblocks">
  <div ng-bind-html="block.content"></div>
</div>
```

in my partial.

The API response looks, roughly, like this:

```
{ htmlblocks: [
    { content: '<p><img data-is-gallery="true" id="img0001" src=""></p>' }
  ], images: {
    img0001: { src: "http://example.com/img1.png" }
  }
}
```

What I want to happen is that I can also update the `<img>` elements within an html block; that is, I want to fill in the `src` attribute on the `<img>` element by looking up the `<img id>` in the `images` section of the API response. So the partial writes out the HTML block from the API, and then the `src` attribute of that `<img>` is updated so that it ends up being `<img data-is-gallery="true" id="img0001" src="http://example.com/img1.png">`.

I *thought* the way to do this was with a directive:

```
.directive("isGallery", function() { 
    return { 
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // do something relevant with element here
        }
    } 
});
```

that is, when the partial wrote out the html blocks, the directive would get called because I'm writing HTML with `<img data-is-gallery>` and I have an `isGallery` directive.

However, this doesn't work; the link function isn't ever called.

Am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Comment: Do you have any control over the backend? I.e. can you change what it returns?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Compiling dynamic HTML strings from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database)

Comment: Ed: I can't change the backend. However, I believe I've now solved it, and marked this as a dup.