# how could i get event fire when ng-click

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

i m adding an anchor tag with `ng-click` with the `ng-bind-html` template but the `ng-click` is not triggering... i need a solution triggering the function.

**my template**:

```
$scope.res =$scope.res+'<a href="javascript:void(o)" ng-click="fullfillmentCenter('+row.orderId+')"  title="Send to fullfilment" class="">Send to CA Fullfilment</a>';
```

**my bind html**:

```
<div class="ngCellText" id="div_fullfilment_{{row.getProperty(\'orderId\')}}" ng-bind-html="fullfillment(row.entity)"></div>';
```

**ng-function call**:

```
$scope.fullfillmentCenter = function(orderId){
alert(orderId);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile your html using `$compile` service for any AngularJS bindings to work. Since $compile requires the html element to compile, it would be preferable if you to create a directive. See this SO post [Compiling dynamic HTML strings from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database)

The other alterative that can work if the template is fixed would be to use `ng-include` and include you template. With `ng-include` compile happens automatically.

You can define template as

```
<script type='text\ng-template' id='content'>
   <a href="javascript:void(o)" ng-click="fullfillmentCenter(row.orderId)"  title="Send to fullfilment" class="">Send to CA Fullfilment</a>
</script>
```

Then include it using ng-include anywhere 
`<div ng-include="content">`