# Where and how to modify transcluded content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, transclusion

I want to buid a directive (let's call it "A") that accepts HTML for transcluded content and modify its transcluded content by adding `ng-click` handlers on it using a custom logic.

I thought that the pre-link would be a good place to do this, but apparently I was very wrong (it seems that the docs suggest against it).

Every "A" directive will accept its own (unique) content, so I cannot do this in the compile phase.

In the `link` function I am not sure what I can do...

So, has anyone done anything similar?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention this: The handlers for `ngClick` should be defined on the directive's scope, not the parent scope. I don't know if Angular allows this, but that's what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template you should add ng-transclude on the element want to add your custom html to.

your use of the directive:

```
    <attribute ng-click="clickMe()">
        <div>
            transcluded data
        </div>
    </attribute >
```

and in your template:

```
<span ng-transclude>
</span>
```

Hope it makes sense :)

Comment: But what I want is to add the `ng-click` attributes on the transcluded template using JS code. Where do you do that?

Comment: check this out. http://plnkr.co/edit/ZD8xLh22dwlNAWjWk108?p=preview

Otherwise you need to create an example of what you mean.

Comment: What I mean is to add the `ng-click="clickMe()"` with javascript code written in the directive, then compile it and have it working. I also want to use the directive scope for some `ngClick` operations. I think I have found the solution in those links: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18157958/2173353 http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/transclusion-and-scopes/

Comment: i dont see why you want it written with javascript(when saying javascript i assume you write it in the controller and inject it). You can create a clickMe method on the directive Link function, and then just reference that in the template. Then it will use the directives scope.

Comment: You are right, but I wanted to save the users of the directive to fill in all those `ngClicks` by hand.

Comment: And also, I might need to mix the two scopes which will be somewhat more complex. Anyway, thanks. :)