# How to bind javascript and ng-click event in html element using angular js?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to bind the following json response in my html page. 
**The json is as follows:**

```
{
"key":{
"text":"<p>For more information, please visit  <a href = \"javascript:void(0);\" ng-click = \"customizeWindow('http://www.google.com');\">Support</a> .</p>"
}
}
```

**html page**

```
<div ng-bind-html="message"></div>
```

**Controller Code**

```
$http({
       method: 'GET',
       url:'DAYS.json'

     }).success(function(responsedata) {
        $scope.message=responsedata.key.text;
      }).error(function(responsedata){});
```

**customizeWindow function inside controller**

```
$scope.customizeWindow = function(url) {
        window.open(url, "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes,top=70, left=190, width=970, height=460");
    }
```

The ng-bind-html binds the html tags but it strips off the javascript and ng-click event.
i get only Support when i inspect element and the link does not work.

Please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This happens since angular Automatically uses $sce -> Strict Contextual Escaping. it allows you to ng-bind-html but it doesn't allow you to add possibly malicious code like JS.
What you are after is explicitly trusting that segment as HTML.**

therefore:

```
angular.module('app', ["ngSanitize"]) // You have to include ngSanitize or it wouldn't work.
.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $sce){

$scope.htmlData = <p>For more information, please visit  <a href = \"javascript:void(0);\" ng-click = \"customizeWindow('http://www.google.com');\">Support</a> .</p> //Took from your example.

$scope.$watch("htmlData", function(newValue){
$scope.trustedData = $sce.trustAsHtml(newValuew);
  });
});
```

**HTML Usage:**

```
<p ng-bind-html="trustedData"></p>
```

Angular Resource:

> Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE) is a mode in which AngularJS requires
>   bindings in certain contexts to result in a value that is marked as
>   safe to use for that context. One example of such a context is binding
>   arbitrary html controlled by the user via ng-bind-html. We refer to
>   these contexts as privileged or SCE contexts.
>
> As of version 1.2, Angular ships with SCE enabled by default.

**read on : [Angular on SCE - trustAsHtml method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml)**

Comment: i am using ngSanitize to handle html content. but the issue is it does not bind the javascript function call. Only displays <a>Support</a>

Comment: SCE trustAsHtml will allow you to paste JS as long as you acknowledge that JSON to be trusted. Good Luck

Comment: Hey Thanks ! Yes it worked if i use onclick instead of ng-click.

Do u have solution for binding ng-click events also and how to bind if we have something like {{value}} in the json response and $scope.value ='something based on calculation result' is received from the controller code.

I may have have asked a weird question but i am new to angular js. But surely this is possible may be not with $sce but some other way like $compile. can you help me with this too please?

Answer (score 1):

[ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) content is sanitized by default and its not meant to bring DOM into the page. You would use this method to bring content onto the page. Eg if you have a rich text editor - you want to feed it html content, however sanitized and thats when you use ng-bind-html.

For your purpose I would suggest to use templates or plain model binding.

Source of your json, what ever that is should not really know anything about the consumer side (your page) implementation/technology what if you move away from angularJS and start using Knockout, you will have to change server-side as well, because Knockout will have no idea about ng-click. Just pass back the content like http://www.google.com, 'For more information, please visit' and bind it.

```
 {
        "key":{
        "textsource": { 
                              source :  'http://www.google.com',
                              message : 'For more information, please visit  ' 
                       }
        }
     }

    <p>{{textsource.message}}<div  ng-click="customizeWindow(textsource.source)\">Support</div> </p>
```

If you can't change server side, have a look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/rxsL8n0L/5/) :

1) tell $sce your content is fine

```
 $scope.message = $sce.trustAsHtml(json.key.text);
```

2) recompile your dynamicaly added content

```
  $scope.init = function () {
            var el = document.getElementById("dynamic");
             $compile(el.childNodes[0])($scope);
        };
```

NOTE: the recompile step is manual for now (press the recompile button). Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database) to make it work nicely.

Comment: And what if he can't change the server side?

Comment: @Linial yes sometimes we can't change the server side and then it all gets interesting :) I have updated my answer - have a look at the fiddle ! And don't forget to press the recompile button - I don't have time to finish it off up to fully functional standard, but I guess you get the point.

Comment: @user3861155 any progress with your issue ? Did you run my example does it work for you ?