# Directive within a directive fails to bind event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a simple test page in order to show m problem.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://www.cloud-eight.com/github/litebox/assets/css/litebox.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <test></test>
        <div vfilter>This works</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.cloud-eight.com/github/litebox/assets/js/litebox.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.cloud-eight.com/github/litebox/assets/js/images-loaded.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.js"></script>
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.directive('test', function () {
    return {
        template: '<div href="#searchPopup" target="_self" class="popup">Click Me...<div style="display: none;"><div id="searchPopup">Hello World...<div vfilter>This doesn\'t</div></div></div></div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.liteBox({
                revealSpeed: 400,
                overlayClose: true,
                escKey: true,
                navKey: true,
                callbackInit: function () { },
                callbackBeforeOpen: function () { },
                callbackAfterOpen: function () { },
                callbackBeforeClose: function () { },
                callbackAfterClose: function () { },
                callbackError: function () { },
                callbackPrev: function () { },
                callbackNext: function () { },
                errorMessage: 'Error loading content.'
            });
        }
    };
});
myApp.directive('vfilter', [ function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('linked');

            element.bind('click', function () {
                console.log('clicked');
            });
        }
    }
}]);
myApp.controller('mainCtrl', [function ($scope) {
    console.log('controller loaded');
}]);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yd6qfhw/).

I have a directive `vilter` in my sample. It does adds a binding on the click event that will log on console. For test reasons I make it to log its link working.

I also have another directive that will popup a div. I place the `vfilter` directive both in the main body and in the popup directive.

While both `vfilter`s log their link run, the one inside the popup fails to log the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by checking this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database)

In my directive which would call litebox i added this code in the `callbackAfterOpen`:

```
$compile($('.litebox-overlay').contents())(scope);
```

This made it work.