# Potential overhead with $compile in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In my app, a user triggers AngularJS to load an HTML containing Angular code from DB. 
After loading, Angular should compile and insert content to the div.
I've used an SO answer to solve it https://stackoverflow.com/a/18157958/1392510.
But it has to load seemingly *big* parts of page (more than 10-15 KBs) with this markup:

```
<div dynamic="markUp" ng-model="markUp"></div>
```

And here is `dynamic` directive:

```
app.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(markUp) {
                ele.html(markUp);
                $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

It seems like I am doing it wrong somewhere, because after insertion that `dynamic` div content duplicates the model content.
Is there a more idiomatic way for doing this?

Comment: It's going to be difficult to help without at least the directive's code...

Comment: @jlowcs updated w/ directive's code

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate the model content"?

Comment: @jlowcs I mean that at first code fills model's content w/ `$scope.markUp = data.file;` and then directive fills it's own content w/ above code and compiles it. Is it possible to fill directive contents directly?

Comment: First, I don't see the point of having a ngmodel attribute. Are you sure that the way directives work is clear to you?

Comment: @jlowcs, you're right, I don't understand directives. It works w/o `ng-model="markUp"`. I will read docs on it. Thank you.