# How init controller in Ajax response?

Tags: angularjs

At main page there is initizlization `ng-app` and `ng-controller`:

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <!-- Here is loaded HTML from AJAX response -->
</div>
</body>
```

Ajax response looks as:

```
<div>{{var}}</div>
```

So, this `{{var}}` shows like as text, I think because this HTML is not loaded together with all DOM page. How to fix?

Comment: Ajax means? Are you using $http service?

Comment: No I use AJAX Jquery

Comment: If you modify anything out of angular context, you will have to invoke scope.$digest()

Comment: The main controller `ng-controller="MyController"` does not see that HTML was loaded by ajax

Comment: My be need to re-init controller in ajax response, that it will see loaded `{{var}}`?

Comment: Add $scope.apply() after ajax call in success function. It might work.

Comment: Why not use $http service for ajax request? Using jquery is also possible but you will have to use ng-include

Comment: Tried, I got HTML from ajax, still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is unfortunately not easy at all to do.

In this case you are on the boundary of AngularJS and Jquery.

You can do it like explained in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18157958/669561

But I would propose you to change your strategy and do the Ajax-Request directly with AngularJS `$http`-Service.

You could also include the HTML dynamically with AngularJS by using the [`ng-include`-Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <ng-include src="your url with HTML content">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have made AJAX via $http Angular, when I get HTML from with `ng-controller` in response this still does not work

Comment: Also tried: `request.success(function (data) {
                    $scope.templateForm = data.html;
                });`  `<ng-include src="{{templateForm}}">`

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
.directive('bindUnsafeHtml', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(
                function(scope) {
                    // watch the 'bindUnsafeHtml' expression for changes
                    return scope.$eval(attrs.bindUnsafeHtml);
                },
                function(value) {
                    // when the 'bindUnsafeHtml' expression changes
                    // assign it into the current DOM
                    element.html(value);

                    // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
                    // scope.
                    // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
                    // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                }
            );
        };
    }])
```

Template:

```
<div bind-unsafe-html="templateForm"></div>
```

Ajax response:

```
request.success(function (data) {
  $scope.templateForm = data.html;
});
```