# When I use ng-bind-html, it will not be able to bind $ scope to this content

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

My code as follows:

```
 <div class="arInfo"><p class='article' ng-bind-html="bodyText"></p></div>
```

js:

```
$scope.bodyText = <p>In its decisions, <a href="#" ng-click= "open('http://www.facebook.com')">Facebook</a> ;
$scope.open = function(url){
   window.open(url, '__blank');
```

}

But,when I click here, it will not open a new window.I think it because the $scope did not bind to here.

I try to change my code like this:

```
$scope.bodyText =  $interpolate(<p>In its decisions, <a href="#" ng-click= "open('http://www.facebook.com')">Facebook</a>)($scope);
```

and this:

```
$scope.bodyText =  $compile(<p>In its decisions, <a href="#" ng-click= "open('http://www.facebook.com')">Facebook</a>)($scope);
```

It also cannot work
Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: this will not work.  you cannot attach angular code as string variables without using `$compile`.

Comment: Actually,I use $compile, it also can not work

Comment: basically, this isn't how angular was intended to be used.  Is there some reason you can't use a template or a directive?

Comment: you might follow the recommendations from here: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/09/10/a-journey-with-trusted-html-in-angularjs.aspx.  It recommends a directive to parse the HTML, which includes using `$sce` and `$compile`.

Comment: I think this helps. Also uses a directive - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.bodyText` should be eqaul to a string. So your code should be like this:

```
$scope.bodyText = 
  '<p>In its decisions, <a href="#" ng-click="open('http://www.facebook.com')">Facebook</a>' ;
```

Comment: It also cannot work.I think it because I use the ng-bind-html, but I do not know how to it

Comment: why are you trying to use window.open instead of puting the whole url inside the href? and and then using target="_blank" attribute? It's less complecated.

Comment: Because,this is a hybrid appkication，I need open the link outside the app