# Accordion in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the following link for creating [Accordion](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) in `angular`. Into that, I am sending `HTML` structure from a controller.  But at view side it doesn't show me `Accordion`. Following is a sample code:

```
 var final='<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime"><uib-accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">This content is straight in the template.</uib-accordion-group>'
```

and at view side I am displaying data like:

```
<div ng-bind-html="final"></div>
```

I want to send HTML structure from controller side.
Please help me into this why it  is not showing accordion properly?

Comment: can you create Plunker ?

Comment: No, I am not  creating Plunker. I am new to angular so I don't know my approach is right or wrong can you please help me into this?

Comment: have you set $scope.final ?

Comment: yes, I set $scope as:  $scope.final=final

Comment: Have you declared a dependency on the `ui.bootstrap` and `ui.bootstrap.accordion` modules? Something like that: `var app = angular.module("appModule", ["ui.bootstrap", "ui.bootstrap.accordion"]);`

Comment: I  added all dependency, but it is not showing me accordion properly?

Comment: example [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Is your `final` variable is defined as you shown? In this case your view does not know what is that - 'final'. Its undefined for it.

Try to declare it with the scope: `$scope.final='<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime"><uib-accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">This content is straight in the template.</uib-accordion-group>'` In this case your view see that `final` is `$scope.final` and can read it.

Another way (if you don't want to use $scope) to declare it as controller variable using `this`: `this.final='<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime"><uib-accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">This content is straight in the template.</uib-accordion-group>'`. And you can call it from the view like this: `<div ng-bind-html="yourControllerName.final"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to `$compile` this variable for rendering on the view. You can create a directive that contains [$compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) for rendering. Then you can use it on that view for rendering the dynamic DOM that is in your variable.

Directive:

```
app.directive('compile', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.compile, function(html) {
        elem.html(html);
        $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Like;

```
<div compile="final"></div>
```

Sure, you don't forget to set final variable to $scope. Like;

```
$scope.final = final;
```

or

```
$scope.final='<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime"><uib-accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">This content is straight in the template.</uib-accordion-group>';
```

I think you need to look [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18157958/2324048).