# bind controller on dynamic HTML

Tags: angularjs, ajax, angularjs-scope

I have a HTML page with different sections, which are loaded with AJAX. I have created a controller for each of the sections.

How is possible to bind the controller on a section which has been dynamically added on HTML?

I have found very complicated solutions, which i don't even know if they apply.

I need the most basic, easiest solution, something similiar with `ko.applyBindings($dom[0], viewModel)` for the ones who worked with `KnockoutJs`.

**Index html**

```
<div class="row" ng-app="app">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li>
                <a href="#/profile">Profile</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div id="container"><!-- load dynamic HTML here --></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Dynamic HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="profile">
    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
    <br>
    Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('profile', function ($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});

// load new HTML
// normally this is triggered by a link / button
$(function () {
    $.get("/EditProfile/Profile", function (data, status) {
        $("#container").html(data);
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: The top answer on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database is a very good solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use jQuery to embed html to your container. If you use jQuery, AngularJS can't track DOM manipulations and trigger directives. You can use `ng-include` directive of AngularJS.

In index.html file:

```
...
<div id="container">
   <div ng-include="'/EditProfile/Profile'"></div>
</div>
...
```

If you want you can make that conditional:

```
...
<div id="container">
   <div ng-if="profilePage" ng-include="'/EditProfile/Profile'"></div>
</div>
...
```

With that example, if you set `profilePage` variable to `true`, profile html will be load and render by `ng-include`.

For detailed info take a look to [ngInclude documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude).

By the way, best practice to include views to your layout by triggering same link clicks is using routers. You can use Angular's [ngRoute module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) or [uiRouter](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) as another popular one.

If you use ngRoute module, your index.html looks like that:

```
<div class="row" ng-app="app">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li>
                <a href="#/profile">Profile</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div id="container" ng-view><!-- load dynamic HTML here --></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And with a router configuration like below, profile html will be automatically loaded and rendered by ngRoute inside ngView directive:

```
angular.module('myapp', []).config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
   .when('/profile', {
    templateUrl: '/EditProfile/Profile',
    controller: 'ProfileController'
  });
});
```

Comment: Does `templateUrl` needs to be a physical path? `/EditProfile/Profile` is a server-side entry point, and does not trigger :(

Comment: My bad! was missing the `ng-view` directive