# Link dynamic HTML to $scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using Angular 1.4.8.  I'm trying to dynamically generate a table where the contents of the cells will be injected from variables in my controller.

I've used the `$compile` service to do something similar when making a directive, but `$compile` doesn't seem to work here.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

#### html

```
<div ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <div ng-bind-html="tableHtml"></div>
</div>
```

#### factory.js

```
var table = {
    title: "table title"
};

factory.buildHtml = function() {
    return "<div>{{ table.title }}</div>";
} 

factory.getTable = function() {
    return table;
};
```

#### controller.js

```
$scope.table = SimpleFactory.getTable();
$scope.tableHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(SimpleFactory.buildHtml());
// also tried:
// $scope.tableHtml = $compile($sce.trustAsHtml(SimpleFactory.buildHtml()))($scope);
// and:
// $scope.tableHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($compile(SimpleFactory.buildHtml())($scope));
```

The html just outputs the text `{{table.title}}`, which is predictable, but I want it to link to the scope to pull the `title` property from my `$scope.table` variable (i.e. I want it to write "table title").  Any suggestions?

---

#### Edit

I created a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8JlXPwiJZMawr1VZdQDg?p=preview) to demonstrate my problem.

In addition to my original code, I added some code from the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database) to my plunkr to demonstrate that it doesn't work how I want it to work.  I believe it is a distinct problem: since the code is coming from a variable in my factory, the custom directive isn't recognized because the variable text (e.g. `"<div>{{ table.title }}</div>"` or `"<div dynamic='table.title'></div>"`) isn't being compiled before its inserted into my page.

There is probably a way to make a directive that solves my problem, but that is the purpose of this question because I don't know how to do that.

---

#### Edit #2

It turns out that this was in fact a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database), though I didn't understand it at the time.

The solution is to add the directive outlined in the answer to the above question, then display the data with `<div dyanmic="tableHtml"></div>` instead of using `ng-bind-html`.  So the correct, working HTML page is below:

#### html

```
<div ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <div dyanmic="tableHtml"></div>
</div>
```

These edits are also saved in the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8JlXPwiJZMawr1VZdQDg) that I made.

Comment: could you build a plunkr?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database?rq=1). Can you not make a directive and use `$compile` within it?

Comment: See edits above - I think this is a distinct problem because the html tag that would contain the custom directive is not hard-coded into my page.  The entire html tag would be dynamically generated, so the custom directive isn't compiled either.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it turns out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database) really did contain the answer.

I was trying to insert the data incorrectly.  Once I added `<div dynamic="tableHtml"></div>`, the data displayed correctly.