# how dynamically create div without ng-repeat,angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I need to generate 'div' dynamically without the help of ng-repeat and also different data in the scope.

```
<div attribute={{atrb}}>{{name}}</div> (<- dynamic div).
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.GenerateDiv = function()
{
$scope.name = "praveen";
$scope.atrb = "01";
}
```

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to use `ng-repeat` when it's clearly the best and simplest solution ?

Comment: you can create a directive, where you can pass data, and a template. In the template you can put the html

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf), or [$compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database)

Answer (score 2):

```
You can do it like

$scope.str = ''
for ( i = 0 ; i < arrayofdata ; i++ ){
  $scope.str += "<div>"+arrayofdata[0].ex+"</div>"
}


use Sanitize filter the following link contains log
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

then create html like this
<div>
{{str | Sanitize}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a single `div` you use `ng-if` to control the creation of it:

```
<div attribute="{{atrb}}" ng-if="name">{{name}}</div>
```

When the condition is not met the `div` is not created. When the condition becomes true, the `div` will be added to your DOM.

If you need several of them then store the parameters in an array and use `ng-repeat`.

Comment: it is not single,i need to generate multiple div

Comment: that's what `ng-repeat` is for.