# How to bind a controller to loaded html ( Angularjs )

Tags: html, angularjs, load

please check this [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/WqivzxsVmmEVij6aD23x)

here is my question how can I bind a controller to Page2Controller to print some thing in

```
{{wat}}
```

Comment: You need to load the html, then use [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) to compile it.

Comment: where shall I use it?

Comment: Isn't that what directive is for?

Comment: I'm new in Angular :) can you clearify it? pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to use `$compile` in the controller.

> Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template function, which can then be used to link scope and the template together.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http, $sce, $compile) {
  $scope.wat = 'blablalba';
  $http.get("page2.html").then(function (response) {
    var str = '<div ng-controller="Page2Controller"> {{wat}} <div style="background: red; height: 50px; width: 50px"></div> </div>';
    var cont = $compile(response.data)($scope);
    angular.element(document.querySelector('p')).append(cont);
  });
});

app.controller('Page2Controller', function($scope) {

});
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/cOu69mPhfrvaA1buDUjT?p=preview

The better way is to using a directive like in this answer: [Compiling dynamic HTML strings from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database#18157958)

Comment: thank you, just a question how can I bind a loaded controller I mean :
var str = '<div ng-controller="Page2Controller"> {{wat}} <div style="background: red; height: 50px; width: 50px"></div> </div>
app.controller('Page2Controller', function($scope) {

});';

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. `I bind a loaded controller`? What do you mean by `bind`?