# Parse directive from text returned from ajax - angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive in angularjs, and success to use it like below:

```
<div my-directive my-data="{}"></div>
```

can show `<div>Hello</div>`

When I load it from an ajax call. For example, my data returned from ajax call:

```
$scope.ajaxData = {title: 'Title', data = '<div>load from directive like this: <div <div my-directive my-data="{}"></div></div>'}
```

and in my template.

```
<div>Title: <span>{{ajaxData.title}}</span></div>
<div ng-bind-html="ajaxData.data"></div>
```

But it not bind to directive, just show html code:

```
 <div my-directive my-data="{}"></div>
```

Would you please tell me how to bind the directive from text like my case

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you missing a module reference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Compiling dynamic HTML strings from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database)

Comment: You need to pass it through the $compile service, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database