# Directive not being triggered

Tags: angularjs

I have my `main.controller.js` which has a simple json object within it.

```
$scope.sections = [
    {
        id: "landing",
        description: "<div><img pinch-zoom src='public/img/model.png'></div>"
    }
];
```

And in my view, I have an `ng-repeat` which loops through my `$scope.sections`.

```
<md-content>
    <div ng-repeat="section in sections">
        {{ section.description }}
    </div>
</md-content>
```

However when I'm outputting `{{ section.description }}` the directive attached to the img is not firing. It's almost as if it's being ignored. Here is the output -- my pinch-zoom is completely removed:

```
<img src='public/img/model.png'>
```

If I apply the directive to an image not within my ng-repeat, the directive fires just fine.

I tried the following within my ng-repeat, but to no avail.

```
<div ng-bind-html="section.description"></div>
```

Comment: use sanitize module of angular application. the image is not getting render becase of the html tag is getting ignored by angular

Comment: @AniruddhaDas just to clarify: the image is getting rendered, but not it's directive. So I see the image just fine, but the directive is not there.

Comment: got it now. try to compile the html in angularjs.

Comment: Ah that is an interpolation problem. You should pass the outputted description into the compilation of angular :)

Comment: Ok, got this working by following [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database)

Answer (score 0):

use the $sanitize and $sce to clean the html

```
 <script>
     angular.module('sanitizeExample', ['ngSanitize'])
       .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
         $scope.snippet =
           '<p style="color:blue">an html\n' +
           '<em onmouseover="this.textContent=\'PWN3D!\'">click here</em>\n' +
           'snippet</p>';
         $scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function() {
           return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.snippet);
         };
       }]);
 </script>
```

Comment: So this does include the directive name in the img tag html. But the directive still isn't firing.