# ng-click doesn't work inside an <a> tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jstree

I'm working with `jstree`, and foreach node I want to add a set of action buttons as following :

```
<span class="action-button-container">
    <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Nouveau" ng-click="createNode($event)">
        <md-icon class="material-icons">add_circle</md-icon>
    </md-button>
    <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Modifier" ng-click="renameNode($event)">
        <md-icon class="material-icons">edit</md-icon>
    </md-button>
    <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Supprimer" ng-click="removeNode($event)">
        <md-icon class="material-icons">delete_circle</md-icon>
    </md-button>
</span>
```

So what I did is in the directive I created, which wraps jstree, I iterate over nodes and concat these action buttons with the node's text :

```
value.map(function(node){
    node.text = node.text + addActionButtons();
    return node;
});
```

`addActionButtons()` will simply return the action buttons string in above.

So in this case jstree will add the action buttons inside an `a` tag, as following :

```
<a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="ajson1_anchor">
   <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>Label 1
   <span class="action-button-container">
      <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Nouveau" ng-click="createNode($event)">
         <md-icon class="material-icons">add_circle</md-icon>
      </md-button>
      <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Modifier" ng-click="renameNode($event)">
         <md-icon class="material-icons">edit</md-icon>
      </md-button>
      <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Supprimer" ng-click="removeNode($event)">
         <md-icon class="material-icons">delete_circle</md-icon>
      </md-button>
   </span>
</a>
```

The problem I'm facing here is that when I click on some action button it doesn't trigger the `ng-click`.

How can I solve this ?

## Update:

When I tried to use `onclick="alert('test')"` it worked, so the problem is only with the `ng-click`, I think I have to do something like this :

```
node.text = node.text + $compile(addActionButtons())(scope);
```

But this adds a string `[Object object]` in front of my nodes, and not the action buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `href="#"` to `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: Well I can't do that unfortunately since the a is generated with the jstree plugin, and I'm not the one who creates it in my code.

Comment: I found a solution whre I can add the `javascript:void(0)` but still it doesn't work

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, since onclick works

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you are suffering from is since AddActionButtons is generating a string dynamically, Angular does not recognize the directives as existing.

You will probably need to use the $compile service:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Also, consult this answer:

[Compiling dynamic HTML strings from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database)

Comment: I already know about the `$compile` service, but unfortunately it won't work in this case, please, check my update.

Comment: I'm assuming you need to return the node as part of `value.map` for jsTree to work? When you concatenate an object (what gets returned from `$compile`) to a string, the string gets coerced to `[object Object]`.

Comment: Personally, I would recommend looking for an existing Angular-based tree directive that works within the framework rather than using a non-angular jQuery plugin.

Comment: Well that's the problem, I couldn't find any decent angular based treeview, and if you found some they are just wraps to the jstree jQuery plugin, so I did the same and I created a directive that wraps the jstree jQuery plugin.