# Nested ng-repeat with ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to render a list of widgets on a page from my controller. Each widget has its own render function that returns a safe HTML string.

My first part of my `ng-repeat` (outside layer) looks like this:

```
$scope.renderWidgets = function() {
  var html = "";
  html += "<div ng-repeat='widget in widgets'>";
  html += "<div ng-bind-html='widget.render()'></div>"
  html += "</div>";
  return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
}
```

As you can see I have `ng-bind-html` inside my `ng-repeat` which is calling a function named .`render()` located inside `widget`:

```
this.render = function() {
  var html = "";
  html += "<div ng-repeat='choice in widget.choices'>";
  html += "{{choice.name}}";
  html += "</div>";
  return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
}
```

I also have a directive that I use to `$compile` the above HTML string into AngularJS.

If I run the above code the `widget.render()` function gets called just fine but the output on the page will look like this: `{{choice.name}}` and not the value inside `choice.name`.

As you can see I am trying to do another `ng-repeat` inside `ng-bind-html` with the `widget` object from my first `ng-repeat`.

Is this even possible what I am trying to do here (I am new to AngularJS)? If yes then what am I doing wrong? Or is there another way to resolve my problem?

I am using the latest AngularJS (v. 1.7.9).

**UPDATE**

I think I know the issue. When I call my first function `$scope.renderWidgets()` the returned HTML will be automatically compiled(the first `ng-repeat`) at which point the `ng-bind-html` gets triggered returning a non-compiled HTML string. Now I have to figure out a way to `$compile` the returned HTML from my `ng-bind-html` directive.

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ng-bind-html` directive only binds HTML. It does not *compile* HTML. This was a deliberate decision by the AngularJS team to avoid security problems.

You state that you have a directive that compiles HTML. Let's assume the directive is:<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18157958/5535245)</sup>

```
app.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
        ele.html(html);
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Then use it in your nested code:

```
$scope.renderWidgets = function() {
  var html = "";
  html += "<div ng-repeat='widget in widgets'>";
  ̶h̶t̶m̶l̶ ̶+̶=̶ ̶"̶<̶d̶i̶v̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶b̶i̶n̶d̶-̶h̶t̶m̶l̶=̶'̶w̶i̶d̶g̶e̶t̶.̶r̶e̶n̶d̶e̶r̶(̶)̶'̶>̶<̶/̶d̶i̶v̶>̶"̶
  html += "<div dynamic='widget.render()'></div>"
  html += "</div>";
  return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
}
```

For more information, see

- [Compiling dynamic HTML strings from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database) — [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18157958/5535245)

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. I would also note for other people that I had to remove `$sce.trustAsHtml()` from my second `ng-repeat` to avoid an infinite digest loop error.